# Append html within anchor tag using jquery(not javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html code

```
<a href="javascipt:void(0)" class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
<span>Thutmekri</span>
</a>
```

Which i want to change into

```
<a href="javascipt:void(0)" class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
<span>1 - Test Setup123</span><div><b></b></div>
</a>
```

How can I achieve this using jquery(not javascript)?

`$(".chosen-single").text()` changes text under anchor tag, but how can i change it having some html as well??

in javascript we have `innerHTML`.

What is equivalent in jquery?

Comment: there is append , prepend and others http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Comment: `.html()` is all you need...

Comment: append/prepend will not allow you to change existing content.. Please pay attention to the text change inside of the span... so yes .html() is what you want in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.html()`/`.html(newhtml)` for getting/setting html content:

```
 $(".chosen-single").html('<span>1 - Test Setup123</span><div><b></b></div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
$(".chosen-single").html(yourHtml)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the inner text in span, you can use jQuery html():

```
$(".chosen-single span").html('1 - Test Setup123');
```

Then you can append the div after the span, by using jquery insertAfter():

```
$('<div><b></b></div>').insertAfter('.chosen-single span');
```

Comment: two steps vs just using .html()

Comment: This is a bonus - more control. You have no idea what he/she wants to do with the code in question

Comment: i dont disagree, was just saying two steps vs one.. Each case is different.. In this case .html does the trick alone.

Comment: Yes, html() will suffice for the answer - but it's a stale solution. I would think going a step further would be encouraged. Each to his own I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Or just do it like this, gives you more control:

```
$('.chosen-single').find('span').prepend('<div><b></b></div>');
```

Name the spans with a class or id to make it more specific.

Comment: This does not change the existing innerText... So would not work.. Not in the supplied example anyway.